# Should we use separate includes and classes folders for front end and backend (admin panel)?

Tags: php

I am developing a website which has two phases - front end for public users and back end for admin panel like all other websites have usually. I want to know that should i have to create separate includes and classes folders for front end and backend (under admin folder) or should i use common folder for both areas? The front end files are put at root level. There is another folder called admin which have all admin files and folders inside it. So if i create classes and includes folder in it (under admin folder) and use the same folders for using in front end also then would it be wise? Continuing with the same thoughts should the db configuration files be separate for both ends? How do professional do the same?

**EDIT -**

I am doing the project in core PHP and no framework is there. Can you guide me better professional directory structure?

Comment: Are these classes shared by both sections? Then yes put in a shared location. Ultimately your framework probably dictates what you do.

Comment: if you think the front-end could be corrupted somehow by who manage the application then have separated files could be useful to prevent backend from being corrupted as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use MVC approach for this matter

and I think it depends on kind of work your doing, I don't think it matters that much.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use the same folders as there would be many common classes and includes in both levels of your site. This makes things easier to manage.

You might put 'admin only' classes in a subfolder so that you might distinguish them properly.

Comment: if i m using same common folders to both front end and back end then path problem is arising.

Comment: Use paths relative to document(site) root.


      
`<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/path/to/classes.php" ?>`